# disable navigating away from a GWT place until some condition is met

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT place where a user must create some object before he/she can navigate away from there.
I tried using

```
eventBus.addHandler(PlaceChangeRequestEvent.TYPE, new PlaceChangeRequestEvent.Handler() {
  @Override
  public void onPlaceChangeRequest(PlaceChangeRequestEvent event) {
    event.setWarning("must create the object");
  }
});
```

but this shows a warning box and then user can click "OK" and still leave the place.
I can put the enforcing code to my PlaceController instance, but I thought maybe there was a way to call something like event.cancel() when I get a PlaceChangeRequestEvent instance.

Comment: Have you tried previewing the event, and then canceling it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076004/gwt-event-preview-vs-event-handler

Answer (score 1):

If you use GWTP, you can call [PlaceManager's setOnLeaveConfirmation method](http://arcbees.github.io/GWTP/javadoc/apidocs/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/PlaceManager.html#setOnLeaveConfirmation%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to lock a user in a particular place with the stock `PlaceController`.

Navigating between places has been modeled after navigating between web pages, because users shouldn't have to even know they're actually not leaving the page: they're in their browser, why would it work differently on that site/app compared to another?